# How to create backstack for Android notification pendingIntent when nextIntent displays a web page in devices web browser

Tags: android, android-notifications

My current android application creates local notifications.

When the user clicks on one of these notifications they navigate to the android devices built in web browser to see the full item detail.

When the user clicks BACK from this web page hosted in the build in web browser i want the user to navigate BACK into my app.

this is how i have set up the pendingIntent for my notification

```
   val pendingIntent = TaskStackBuilder.create(context).run {
       addNextIntent(/* The Intent to navigate BACK to */)
       addNextIntentWithParentStack(/* Intent to show web page in Browser */)
       getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
    }
```

the issue is the web back displays fine, however when the user navigates BACK they navigate to the devices home screen and not into my app.

i am supposed to set the parent activity in the manifest as detailed in the docs
however when the detail is hosted by the devices web browser how should i set `android:parentActivityName`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to your Intent (the one in `addNextIntentWithParentStack` I presume)?

Related docs:

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
- https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack#TaskLaunchModes